# Vue parse object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm doing some customizations to [Vuexy admin panel](https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/documentation/).

I'm trying to get theme configuration information from the backend, but I'm doing something wrong. When the client is logging in, I'm using `setItem`, like so:

```
localStorage.setItem('themeConfig', JSON.stringify(response.data.theme_config))
```

I have tested that and response.data.theme_config is returning json from backend, like so:

```
"theme_config": {
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "disableCustomizer": 1,
  "disableThemeTour": 1,
  "footerType": "static",
  "hideScrollToTop": 0,
  "mainLayoutType": "vertical",
  "navbarColor": "#fff",
  "navbarType": "static",
  "routerTransition": "fade-bottom",
  "rtl": 0,
  "sidebarCollapsed": 0,
  "theme": "dark",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to call `getItem` like so:

```
const themeConfig = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("themeConfig"))
```

But every time this is returning `[object Object]`

I tried without success both:

- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("themeConfig")))`
- `JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("themeConfig"))`

And when I try `console.log('asdasdadeasd' + JSON.stringify(response.data.theme_config))` I receive this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "disableCustomizer": 1,
  "disableThemeTour": 1,
  "footerType": "static",
  "hideScrollToTop": 0,
  "mainLayoutType": "vertical",
  "navbarColor": "#fff",
  "navbarType": "static",
  "routerTransition": "fade-bottom",
  "rtl": 0,
  "sidebarCollapsed": 0,
  "theme": "dark",
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null
}
```

Comment: Localstorage only stores *strings*. Hence you need to `JSON.parse` it first.

Comment: I just did like so and received like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Please update the question with the exact code you tried.

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: It seems you have stored invalid JSON. What exactly is returned by `localStorage.getItem("themeConfig")`?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You did not address my question. What exactly is returned by `localStorage.getItem("themeConfig")`? Please provide a [mcve].